# SSIS Error with OLE DB destination when executing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledbconnection, dataflow, oledbexception

I'm New to SSIS so have been following some online tutorials. I have come across the following and cannot figure out what has happened. the error is with the OLE DB connection

if anyone can point me in the right direction to getting this resolved that would be great.

```
SSIS package "c:\users\****\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\tutorials\tutorials\basicpackage.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x80049304 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DC at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The processing of file "L:\sql queries\SSIS TUTORIAL\apps.txt" has started.
Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DE at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The total number of data rows processed for file "L:\sql queries\SSIS TUTORIAL\apps.txt" is 5.
Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [23]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'ssis.dbo.Apps'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.".
Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [23]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (23) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (36). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x402090DD at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The processing of file "L:\sql queries\SSIS TUTORIAL\apps.txt" has ended.
Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB Destination" wrote 4 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Task failed: Data Flow Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at basicpackage: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (3) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "c:\users\****\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\tutorials\tutorials\basicpackage.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

the First error  ii cannot resolve. I have checked the connection, the destination table in the SQL DB and do not know what the issue is. could it be to do with Windows Authentication for access to db?

```
Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [23]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
```

Comment: Include the contents of the file `apps.txt` and the definition of the `dbo.Apps` table

Comment: `"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID'` . Either remove the NOT NULL restriction of ID column(not recommended), or check for NULLs in source.

Comment: @Prabhat-G I thought if I don't link anything to the DB column 'ID' in the Mapping section of the Connection manager then there wouldn't be an issue. the 'ID' column will just auto increment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error looks to be explained by this line in the output

> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot insert the
>   value NULL into column 'ID', table 'ssis.dbo.Apps'; column does not
>   allow nulls. INSERT fails.".

Without knowing the contents of the file `L:\sql queries\SSIS TUTORIAL\apps.txt`
and design of the `SSIS.dbo.Apps` table it difficult to pin point the exact area of the problem other than to say that the table has a column called `ID` which doesn't accept NULLs and the file has a row where the contents of the corresponding column has a NULL .

[EDIT}
Update following OP's comments

You seem to have a table like so

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Apps (
      Id    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY
    , Apps  CHAR (1)
    , Rating CHAR   (1)
    , Summary CHAR  (1)
);
```

And trying to insert something like this, nothing in the Id column

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Apps
( Id, Apps, Rating, Summary)
VALUES
(NULL , '1', '2', '3' )
```

You will get this error

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 5 Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'Id', table 'xStuff.dbo.Apps'; column does not allow nulls.
>   INSERT fails.

So I would recommend you change the table definition like so, as you want the ID column to auto-increment, `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`  to an `INT IDENTITY`

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Apps (
      Id    INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    , Apps  CHAR (1)
    , Rating CHAR   (1)
    , Summary CHAR  (1)
);
```

and this this will work

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Apps
(     Apps
    , Rating
    , Summary
)
VALUES
(  '1', '2', '3'), (  'A', 'B', 'C')
```

see output

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. my apps.txt file contains 3 headers App|Rating|Summary. my SQL db table APPs contains 4 columns ID|App|Rating|Summary. the ID is set as PK and datatype set to uniqueIdentifier meaning it does not allow nulls. I didn't think this would be a problem I thought this would get populated when package would run?

Comment: a uniqueidentifier doesn't auto increment and doesn;t have a default value unless you create a default constraint